# Не получается передать props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается передать **props.children**, его просто не видит компилятор и выдает ошибку **TypeError: props.children is not a function**

```
<ItemList
    onItemSelected={this.onPersonSelected}
    getData={this.swapiService.getAllPersons}>

    {(i) => (
      `${i.name} (${i.birthYear})`
    )}

  </ItemList>
```

Эту функцию передаю в компоненту как children
В самой компоненте есть функция, которая использует ее для отобрадения label

```
const renderItems = arr => {
return arr.map(item => {
  const { id } = item
  const label = props.children(item)
  return (
    <li
      className="list-group-item"
      key={id}
      onClick={() => onItemSelected(id)}
    >
      {label}
    </li>
  );
});
```

Я ломаю голову 2й час и не понимаю в чем заключается ошибка....

Comment: `const label = props.children(item)` ты какую то чепуху делаешь.

Comment: Можно узнать почему?

Comment: Ну ты в компоненте принимаешь пропсы, правильно? Правильно. А props.children это что? Это грубо говоря то, что находится между открывающим и закрывающим тегом `<Component.name>**ВОТ ТУТ**</Component.name>` в родительском компоненте.

Comment: Окей, тогда для общего развития можешь подсказать я компоненте пропсы принимаю вот так вот 
const ItemList = ({getData, onItemSelected}, ...props) =>{}
И почему то ошибка, когда я просто поставил пропс = props => {}, все работало, по факту же такая же запись или нет?

Comment: Мне сложно что то сказать без рабочего кода, так как я даже не понимаю что ты пытаешься сделать в том примере который скинул. Если хочешь можешь закинуть сюда https://codesandbox.io/ код, я поковыряюсь. Только не весь, сделай минимальный пример того, что не получается.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-goodall-cvyi1 вопрос меня интересовал, почему показывает undefined в консоли, если по факту я  передал children'a

Comment: { onItemSelected, getData, ...props}

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-curie-mqi6g

Comment: я кстати не знал что так можно делать

Comment: передавать функцию как children )

Comment: ну и это ``{i => `${i.name} (${i.birthYear})`}`` какая то нечитабельная хрень ) я еле разобрал на ночь глядя)

Comment: хвпзхазпхазп, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В компаненте выше (App) удали или закоменть этот код и все заработает

```js
<div className="row mb2">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <ItemList
                onItemSelected={this.onPersonSelected}
                getData={this.swapiService.getAllPlanets}
                renderItem = {(item) => item.name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <PersonDetails personId={this.state.selectedPerson} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row mb2">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <ItemList
                onItemSelected={this.onPersonSelected}
                getData={this.swapiService.getAllStarships}
                renderItem = {(item) => item.name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <PersonDetails personId={this.state.selectedPerson} />
          </div>
        </div>`
```

Comment: Извините, уточните пожалуйста, а где вы видите этот код в вопросе?